# How to make a mute command take in a user id and a mention

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a mute command or any command that takes either a mention of a user id. both will work.

I really only need help with this part:
`async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):`

so i can do /mute id **or** /mute @Member and both will work

Comment: that should work

Comment: that should work, but you need `intents.members` enabled.

Comment: is doesn't work it just outputs member not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work!

async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member):

That piece of code was working I needed to turn intents on and turn on user tracking in the discord developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is :

```
@client.command(aliases=["m", "M", "Mute"]) #new one to karim
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def mute(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    command_name = "mute"
    author = ctx.author
    await member.edit(mute=True)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} is muted")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

and the unmute command :

```
@client.command(aliases=["unm", "UNM", "Unmute"]) #new one to karim
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def unmute(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    command_name = "unmute"
    author = ctx.author
    await member.edit(mute=False)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} is unmuted")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
```

Comment: the '#new one to karim' is nothing it is just cuz i copied all of this from my code

Comment: it doesn't work and if i put a reason it also doesn't work